# C String -- Sort by first-word length

Tags: c, string, sorting, pointers, boolean

I'm self-studying C and doing an exercise that, among other things, asks me to sort a list of user-entered strings by length of the first word in the string. The other functions in the exercise (including sorting the string by entire length) were easy to write. I've been working on this one for over three hours and can't get it to work. I'm sorting an array of pointers-to-char, and then printing them with a for loop in the main() function.

There's probably a much easier way to do this, but even if so, I cannot understand why this function doesn't work. I've made about thirty changes to it and the sort still comes out pretty random.

```
void srtlengthw(char * strings[], int n)
{
int top, seek, ct, ct_temp, i;
int ar_ct[n]
char * temp;
bool inWord;

for (top = 0, ct = 0, i = 0, inWord = false; top < n - 1; top++)
{
        while (strings[top][i])
        {
                if (!isblank(strings[top][i]))
                {
                        i++;
                        ct++;
                        inWord = true;
                }
                else if (!inWord)
                        i++;
                else
                        break;
        }
        ar_ct[top] = ct;
        for (seek = top + 1, ct = 0, i = 0, inWord = false; seek < n; seek++)
        {
                while(strings[seek][i])
                {
                        if (!isblank(strings[seek][i]))
                        {
                                i++;
                                ct++;
                                inWord = true;
                        }
                        else if (!inWord)
                                i++;
                        else
                                break;
                }
                ar_ct[seek] = ct;
                if (ar_ct[top] > ar_ct[seek])
                {
                        ct_temp = ar_ct[top];
                        ar_ct[top] = ar_ct[seek];
                        ar_ct[seek] = ct_temp;
                        temp = strings[top];
                        strings[top] = strings[seek];
                        strings[seek] = temp;
                }
        }
}}
```

Example of wrong output, as requested:

Input:

Mary

had

a

little

lamb

that

was

sacrificed

to

Satan

=========

Output:

had

a

little

lamb

that

was

sacrificed

to

Mary

Satan

And here's an example of a much simpler function that worked properly. It's meant to sort the pointers by length of the entire string rather than just the first word. I tried to model the word-length sort function on this one, but I'm apparently having trouble dealing with my counter variables and maybe my bool flag right.

```
void srtlength(char * strings[], int n)
{
        int top, seek;
        char * temp;

        for (top = 0; top < n - 1; top++)
                for (seek = top + 1; seek < n; seek++)
                        if (strlen(strings[top]) > strlen(strings[seek]))
                        {
                               temp = strings[top];
                               strings[top] = strings[seek];
                               strings[seek] = temp;
                        }
}
```

For Craig, hopefully this helps?
Input:

```
They say it's lonely at the top, and whatever you do
You always gotta watch m*********s around you
Nobody's invincible
No plan is foolproof
We all must meet our moment of truth
The same sheisty cats that you hang with and do your thang with
Could set you up and wet you up, n***a, peep the language
It's universal
You play with fire, it may hurt you, or burn you
Lessons are blessins you should learn through
```

Output for me:

```
You always gotta watch m********s around you
Nobody's invincible
No plan is foolproof
We all must meet our moment of truth
The same sheisty cats that you hang with and do your thang with
Could set you up and wet you up, n***a, peep the language
It's universal
You play with fire, it may hurt you, or burn you
Lessons are blessins you should learn through
They say it's lonely at the top, and whatever you do
```

Comment: a) "Pointer to char"? I see a pointer to pointer to char. Big difference. b) How about separating sorting and comparing two elements? Will be much easier for you too.

Comment: Please add an example where output is wrong.

Comment: "an array of pointers to char", which I believe amounts to a pointer to pointer-to-char, at least insofar as the argument I'm passing is concerned. In the main() function, it's declared as "char * ptstr[10];". Each element is set to the corresponding member of "char st[10][80]", which is where the user input went. My C book advises sorting pointers rather than sorting arrays, and this setup has worked fine for my other functions in this program.

Separating sorting and comparing two elements? I don't see quite what you mean.

Comment: Jay: I added an example.

Comment: For leaving the original sequence untouched and simply providing sort "bed" of pointers, your book is accurate, and it at least sounds like you're trying to do it correctly. Anyway, so am I correct in understanding that each original string entry could have more than a single word (in the 80-chars per, there may be whitespace)? is that correct? You're trying to dissect the first word via whitespace detection, then using that discovered word as the sort data for that item?

Comment: Craig: Yes, that's correct. To save time on testing the function, I've used single words. Since they're by definition the first word of their respective strings, they should still be sorted by length, right?

Comment: I'm also about to add an example of a much simpler function that worked correctly, which sorted the strings by length of the entire string.

Comment: Also: I've been working on coding all day today, and I'm inexperienced enough that doing this much with no breaks has fried my brain lol. So my apologies (and many lulz for everyone) if there's a super simple way to get the first-word length and compare them in the sort-function.

Comment: It isn't simple, and honestly, your code is ok for someone that isn't language-fluent. don't beat yourself up. I'm finishing a comparative function that does what your task is (apparently), and there is enough there to warrant some significant inline comments. I don't suppose the actual *input strings*, separated by line, are possible to append to your question text?

Comment: I inserted some sample input and output strings already (again, I just used one-word strings for simplicity), between the trouble function and the simpler working function example. Do you mean something different?

Comment: Yes, I meant a raft of strings with multiple *words* in each string, separated by newlines. Use the ctrlK formatter (it will help, trust me). I may just slurp up your opening paragraph, broken into 3-5 words per string line just for kicks. Would be nice to have real test data though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Ctrl+K. Hopefully what I added is what you're asking for.

Comment: Ok. I have to hit some q-time with the wife, but [read this carefully](http://ideone.com/UhwLKr). I documented the hell out of the comparator function, and its an example that uses `qsort()`. to do what you're trying to. Best of luck.

Comment: I could edit this for offensive language, but as it is in the input/output examples that would make no sense, so voting for closure instead.

Comment: Offensive language used in examples.

Comment: Sorry, I should've paid more attention to the terms of use. New here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for output similar to that of the example code that you posted, then I suggest using it as a template for a version with your expected behavior. The key that I'm looking to point out is that it sorts by the return value of the `strlen` function.

`strlen` is a function in C's `<string.h>` library (I think?) that returns the length of a C-style string. In C, as you're probably aware, the end of a string is identified by a null terminator, which is represented as a `'\0'`.

While the precise `strlen` may vary from one library to another, here is one standard implementation (made easier to read):

```
int strlen(char * str){
    char * l;
    for(l = str; *l != '\0'; l++);
    return l - str;
}
```

People will likely argue that there are problems with this and it isn't perfect, but it does hopefully show how the length of a string is determined.

Now that we understand that the last example sorts by the total string length, and we know how string length is determined, we can probably make our own version of `strlen` that stops after the first word, instead of stopping at the null terminator:

```
int blank_strlen(char * str){
    char * l;
    for(l = str; *l != '\0' && !isblank(*l); l++);
    return l - str;
}
```

Now, using the example code given:

```
void blank_srtlength(char * strings[], int n)
{
        int top, seek;
        char * temp;

        for (top = 0; top < n - 1; top++)
                for (seek = top + 1; seek < n; seek++)
                        if (blank_strlen(strings[top]) > blank_strlen(strings[seek]))
                        {
                               temp = strings[top];
                               strings[top] = strings[seek];
                               strings[seek] = temp;
                        }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be helpful! A few things I recommend keeping in mind: Firstly, avoid reinventing the wheel; I honestly didn't even look at your code (although I will now) when I noticed that little part at the bottom. It's much easier to modify `strlen` than to make a sorting algorithm from scratch. Secondly, making subroutines (functions) can make your code much more succinct and easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

millinon's answer is a much better way to do it, as it is simpler. However, if you are looking for the reason why your code isn't working, it is due to your variables only being reset outside of each loop.
This code:

```
    for (seek = top + 1, ct = 0, i = 0, inWord = false; seek < n; seek++)
    {
            while(strings[seek][i])
```

only sets ct, i and inWord **once**, before the loop is first started. When the program loops around, the values of ct, i and inWord will be kept from the last iteration.

Moving the assignments inside the loop like this:

```
    for (seek = top + 1; seek < n; seek++)
    {
            ct = 0;
            i = 0;
            inWord = false;
            while(strings[seek][i])
```

will fix your problem (you have to do it in both places).